# Import JMeter project (ant) to Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jmeter

I'm trying to do something with JMeter code and I have some stupid problem.
I've installed Eclipse Juno, I've installed Ant and fetched JMeter code from SVN, it builds nicely from command line.
Problem is when I'm trying to import JMeter ant project to Eclipse.
In package explorer I'm selecting: `New/Project...`
Then I'm choosing `Java/Java Project from existing Ant Build File`, next
I'm pointing JMeters file: `build.xml`, click Finish
It looks like import was successful but I can see only two folders with source code: `core` and `jorphan`. There should be much more, 12 directories at least.

So what I'm doing wrong? Or How do I fix it?

Comment: Any news on that, was my answer helpful, if yes you should accept it so that it helps others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do the following:

- in eclipse, checkout jmeter from svn
- add java nature to project by modifying .project file (create another java project and copy paste content of .project

  ```
   <projectDescription>
  <name>jmeter</name>
  <comment></comment>
  <projects>
  </projects>
  <buildSpec>
          <buildCommand>
               <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                      <arguments>
                      </arguments>
              </buildCommand>
  </buildSpec>
  <natures>
         <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  </natures>
  </projectDescription>
  ```
- copy eclipse.classpath to .classpath
- call ant download_jars

That's it

Comment: for some reason svn in eclipse doesn't work for me (I did it from command line), but at least you give me a hint how to fix it (it was a bit more complicated), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

build.xml has a eclipse setup target which is not mentioned in MD for some reason.  run `ant setup-eclipse-project` before importing project into eclipse.