# How to run jmeter script from eclipse

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Please let me know whether it is possible to run jmeter script from eclipse?
If yes Please let me know the process.

Comment: First result when searching on google http://people.apache.org/~mkostrze/jmeter-eclipse/index.html

Comment: I have already tried this but the process defined is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import JMeter project (ant) to Eclipse Juno](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725756/import-jmeter-project-ant-to-eclipse-juno)

Comment: I shall try the instruction from: http://people.apache.org/~mkostrze/jmeter-eclipse/index.html
But i found error as: Error validating location: "Could not connect to
:pserver:anoncvs@cvs.apache.org:/home/cvspublic: Cannot connect to host:
Connection timed out: connect"
Keep location anyway?

Comment: The link people.apache.org/~mkostrze/jmeter-eclipse/index.html is about launching jmeter from within the eclipse. But what we want to know is given a jmx script, is there a way to execute it simply as we execute a Junit from the eclipse IDE.

Comment: Are you only thinking to run JMeter from eclipse or want a proper integration of JMeter in Eclipse. I have written a blog on how to integrate JMeter in Eclipse (without errors) which will help in extending JMeter and enjoying all advantages of Eclipse IDE. [http://p3lang.com/2016/03/configure-jmeter-in-eclipse/](http://p3lang.com/2016/03/configure-jmeter-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use Eclipse External Tool**

1. *Eclipse menu*: Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration...
2. The dialog *External Tools Configuration* opens
3. From the tree on the left select *Program*
4. Use *left mouse button* and select from the mouse menu *New* or use the left icon (above the tree) and select *New launch configuration*
5. On the right side of the tree, opens the panel, where details of this new lauch configuration can be filled in
6. Enter as *Name*: **JMeter sample**
7. Enter as *Location*: **The location where JMeter is installed**
   (on windows something like `C:\Program Files\apache\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat`) (on Linux like `/opt/apache/jmeter/bin/jmeter`)
8. Enter as *Working Directory*: **${workspace_loc:/jmeter-project}** (use the button **Browse Workspance...**, to select the project, in your workspace where the JMeter script are located. Here the project `jmeter-project` is shown)
9. Close the dialog by using the button **Run**, which should launch JMeter.

**Info** The icon *Stop*, does not work, as this actually launches a script, which launches the Java application JMeter.

**Optionally add parameters**

1. Enter as *Arguments*: **`-t src\test\jmeter\sample.jmx`** (the path of the JMeter script to launch)
2. Enter as *Arguments*: **`-q src\test\jmeter\environment.properties`** (some external properties file, use `${__P(key-name)}`)

See [JMeter options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) and 
[Parameterising Tests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#parameterising_tests) for the details.

Comment: Is there a possibility that we can run this in maven project?

Comment: @AVI Running JMeter from a Maven project is possible as well. Have a look at this article https://medium.com/@gabriel.starczewski/running-jmeter-tests-with-maven-and-maven-wrapper-6725aa025bd9